# What to do in case of SMTP 421 error?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, pear

I have some PHP code that help send emails.  The way it works is that there is a list of unique keys, every key has to be sent to a different email address.  Sometimes we need to be able to send 1000 of these key out at once, and hence, 1000 emails.

I am using the Pear Mail SMTP code found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page) with gmail.  It works very well when sending just a small number of keys.  However when I try to send many keys (over 100), i often get this error:

[image]

From what I have read, this means that for whatever reason, the SMTP server isn't taking emails right now, and denies the transfer, suggesting to try back later.  I am not quite sure what to do here to handle this problem.  Should I make the script pause for a few seconds and try again?  Does the error mean something different?  What am I to do?

Comment: Do you get that error from the same host most of the time?  You might be getting rate limited or temporarily blocked by an SMTP server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send out the keys in batches of 50, with a small time-interval between each batch. The error means that you are trying to open too many SMTP connections at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Gmail for bulk mail. It's a personal email service, not a bulk mailer.

There are plenty of commercial bulk mail services available. Here are a few; there are others.

- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)
- [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)
- [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) (Simple Email Service)
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/)
- [SocketLabs](http://socketlabs.com/)
- [Mailjet](http://www.mailjet.com/)